# ssh into windows 10 powershell and not get admin rights

Tags: windows-10, ssh, powershell

For ssh I'm used to unix systems. I have "sudo" rights but when I ssh into my account I'm not an admin, I'm just a regular user. To do anything admin I have to "sudo"

The same is true locally. I open a terminal I'm not admin. I'm just a regular use.

Even in Windows 10 if start a powershell I don't have admin rights. To get admin rights I have to specifically open and admin powershell. The default is no admin rights.

I recently setup [ssh with powershell on Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7) but when I ssh into a shell it says have admin rights

```
(New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(
  [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
True
```

How do I can get this to behave the same as if I'd started a powershell locally where it starts without admin rights?

If it's not clear at my desktop I open a command prompt and type `pwsh` and I'm not admin

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\gregg>pwsh
PowerShell 7.0.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

Loading personal and system profiles took 620ms.
❯ (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(
>>   [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
>> ).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
False
```

Do that again except ssh to localhost but somehow I am admin

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\gregg>ssh localhost
gregg@localhost's password:
PowerShell 7.0.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

Loading personal and system profiles took 620ms.
❯ (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(
>>   [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
>> ).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
True
```

Those 2 commands `pwsh` and `ssh localhost` should end up in the same situation but they don't. How to fix so `ssh localhost` behaves the same as `pwsh`

PS: I get that powershell doesn't appear to have a "sudo" type of command nor a way to elevate privileges. That is not my question. My question is when I start powershell locally I'm not admin. When I start it via ssh how do I get it to behave the same

Bonus question: If there is an answer for how to ssh into powershell as a user in the admin group but without admin rights in the powershell what would be the process to optionally start a powershell with admin rights over ssh? (flags, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

The way that Windows starts your desktop without admin rights / elevated (even though your user account is in the Administrators group and should have those permissions), is [UAC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works).

There would need to be some feature built-in to the sshd service that ran the same logic of creating a low-privilege standard access token, instead of starting your shell process with the default admin token.

In the [Windows sshd docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration) this is the most relevant language I could find:

> Note that if the user belongs to the administrator group, %programdata%/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys is used instead.

so it seems that feature doesn't exists today. But if you created a feature request I would +1 it!

---

Other solutions I can think of are "Use a different user" or "Run a different ssh server non-elevated" :(

If you create a different Windows user account not in the Administrators group and SSH into that user, you wouldn't be elevated. That might not be helpful though...

If you started a ssh server non-elevated, the shell process it spawns would also be non-elevated. You could try [installing sshd from WSL](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-ssh-into-wsl2-on-windows-10-from-an-external-machine)? I haven't tried that so I don't know if it would work.

I also thought about [PowerShell Remoting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7.1) but in my testing that always starts an elevated shell, same as SSH.